# Why this function must be static?

Tags: c#

```
public void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
{
    box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;

    box.SelectionColor = color;
    box.AppendText(text);
    box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
}
```

It was `public static void`

But then i had an error on this line in my Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

The error is on the Form1 say:

> Error Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

If i remove the static from the function im getting error on the AppendText say:

> Error Extension method must be static

How do i work with that ?

Comment: `Error Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class` Create a static class and put your code there

Comment: How do you intend to call the method? As an extension method for `RichTextBox`, or as a method in the form? You have given it a `this` parameter like an extension method, but you have put it in your form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because its an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on RichTextBox, it needs to be static, also it needs to be inside a static class.

`this` keyword in method parameters is defining it as an extension method on RichTextBox

```
AppendText(this RichTextBox box.......
```

From [MSDN - Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by
>   using instance method syntax.Their first parameter specifies which type the method operates on, and the parameter is preceded by the **this** modifier.

From [MSDN - this keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is
>   also used as a modifier of the **first parameter of an extension
>   method.**

if you want to create an extension method on RichTextBox, then you can have to define this method as static and also have it in a static non-generic class something like:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
   public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
   {
    box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;

    box.SelectionColor = color;
    box.AppendText(text);
    box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
   } 
}
```

later you can call it like:

```
RichTextBox yourRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
yourRichTextBox.AppendText("Some Text",Color.Blue);
```

Answer (score 2):

The presence of the `this` keyword before the first parameter is for [defining extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042).

```
public void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
//                     ^^^^
```

Extension methods must be inside a static class.

Remove the `this` keyword to make it into an ordinary method.